# Biharmonic equation analysis, change of variables, complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am analyzing the equation

$\big[(1-c)\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4} + (2-c)\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^2\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^4}{\partial y^4}\big]w = 0.$

and $0 \leq c \leq 1$ so that when $c=0$ we have the biharmonic equation.  This equation arises in fracture mechanics.

Questions:

1) Is there an obvious change of variables that I am missing that would result in the biharmonic equation in a new coordinate system?

2) Without such a change of variables, how can I proceed in complex analysis, i.e., to find the general complex solution for the equation at hand?  We know that for the biharmonic equation, for example, this general solution is $f(z) + \bar z g(z)$.

Thank you!